# HTML displaying paragraph only when clicked

Tags: javascript, css, html

I would like to know how can I click on a text, and instead of linking to some external link, I would like to be able to display a paragraph on the same page. 
For example, I want to have a hidden paragraph, and I want for it to be only be displayed when I click on some text.

I thought I can use "id", but I am not sure how!

```
<a id="tips">test</a>
<a href="#tips">Visit the Useful Tips Section</a>
```

Any idea, how I can do this?

Comment: Did you have javascript with this code or is this it?

Comment: No this is it. I didn't know how to add the javascript. I though since there is no fancy movement, this can purely done in HTML. Can you tell me how to add some javascript for this purpose?

Comment: There is no paragraph in your code example, just an internal link. You have not described where the paragraph should appear, what exactly should happen when it is shown (should the rest of the page move down?), and what (if anything) should make it disappear.

Answer (score 1):

you can use jquery to do it easily or if you want to avoid that, here is an alternate solution:

http://blog.movalog.com/a/javascript-toggle-visibility/

```
<script type="text/javascript"> <!--
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    } //--> </script>
```

Simply paste the above snippet of code underneath your  tag and you call it by passing to it the ID of the element you wish to toggle the visibility of (this element can be anything that takes an id attribute). For example

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');">  
Click here to toggle visibility of element #foo</a> <div id="foo">This is foo</div>
```

or, in your case; include the function and:

```
<a id="tips" style="display:none;">test</a>  
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('tips');">Visit the Useful Tips Section</a>
```

Comment: This is nice. But can you please tell me that instead of toggling how can I have a button pops up next to the text (This is foo), and when I click on the button, then it gets closed ? thx

Comment: i'm not sure exactly what you mean, but if you understand the javascript function here you can hack it to do exactly what you want.  maybe you want to functions, one that 'shows' any div and one that 'hides' any div?

Comment: For the very first time that the page loads, how can I make the text to come up as hidden, and then by clicking it actually shows the text. Also, for the first time, I have to click on it twice for the text to hide !!!

Comment: do you have this in there? `style="display:none;"`  maybe there's a typo?  Any div with that should be hidden when the page loads.

Comment: great!  don't forget to mark the correct answer if this worked for you, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily Javascript. Your code is actually working, but you are not noticing it because both elements are one below the other. If you add a `<div>` with some height, you'll notice it.

```
<a href="#tips">Visit the Useful Tips Section</a>
<div style="height: 1000px"></div>
<a id="tips">test</a>
```

(However, I don't mean you *have* to add this `<div>`).

Answer (score 0):

Just takes some basic javascript code. This one right here is a good example. Comment if you want me to explain this in more detail.

```
<html> 
<head> 
<style type="text/css"> 
#text 
{ 
display: none 
} 
</style> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function callMe() 
{ 
document.getElementById("text").style.display = 'block'; 
} 
</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<div id="text">Hello! How are you?</div> 
<form> 
<input type="button" name="button" id="button" value= "Call Me" onclick="javascript:callMe()" /> 
</form> 
<body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try add jquery and show the paragraph on click.

jsfiddle.net/6mk3a0ov/